# Component's JavaScript doesn't execute on routing with React router

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router, components

I'm working on my first React project. I need to style some parts with JS because I'm dependent on the content. I'm calling the JS function from the components `componentDidMount()` upon JQuery's `$(document).ready()` because else it won't find the nodes to style.

When I enter the page or refresh the styling works as planned, but when I use the router's `<Link>` or `<NavLink>` the JS won't load.

Is there a way make it work?

```
class About extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      $(document).ready( function () {
        indentation($('.page__content__career').children(), 85);
        indentation($('.page__about .page__content__text').children(), 100);
      });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page page__about">
        <div className="page__content page__about__content">
          <h1>about</h1>
          <hr />
          <div className="page__content__photo">
            <img src={'../images/profile-picture-square--dark.jpg'} />
          </div>
          <div className="page__content__text">
            <p>Hello, World</p>
          </div>
          <ul className="page__content__career">
            {
              cvList.map( (job) => {
                return (
                  <CVElement
                    startTime={job.startTime}
                    endTime={job.endTime}
                    description={job.description}
                    place={job.place}
                    link={job.link}
                  />
                )
              })
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default About;
```

I also tried calling the respected functions when entering, which did not work

```
    <Route path="/en/about" component={About} onEnter={() => console.log('Entered About')}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery to style? Why use jQuery at all? Just pass your styles in to the appropriate element using the `style={{}}` attribute, like this:

```
<ul className="page__content__career" style={{ marginLeft: '100px' }}>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: I have to loop through the elements and give each a styling based on an index.
I'm using jQuery out of habit, I could get rid of it but i need a function anyways

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it out. It's actually pretty simple. As @Alex Dovzhanyn suggested I got rid of jQuery but then used DOM style objects.

```
componentDidMount() {

      const pageAboutChildren = document.querySelector('.page__about .page__content__text').childNodes;
      const pageAboutCareer = document.querySelector('.page__content__career').childNodes;

      indentation(pageAboutChildren, 100);
      indentation(pageAboutCareer, 85);
      changeColor();
  }
```

with indentation() being:

```
const indentation = (element, indent) => {
  for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].style.marginLeft =  indent * (i+1) + 'px';
  }

}
```

I had some referencing troubles which further confused me
it's not so hard after all